# Using beamer metropolis theme slides after standout are all standout

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I love the `metropolis` theme for beamer. It has a nice feature where you can make a `standout` frame to add emphasis to that particular slide.

However, when I use the `standout` frame, every slide after it is also a `standout` frame. This feels like a bug to me. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the issue you describe. A MWE asuch as the following `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[standout]
\frametitle{standout frame}
contents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frame title}
contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}` results in the expected output with the first and third frame being regular frames and the second frame being a standout frame.

Comment: Since you seem to get a different output, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output/issue you get.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a MWE. While putting a MWE together, I discovered that this is a problem with a related package [beamerswitch](https://github.com/alex-ball/beamerswitch). When I removed that package, the problem went away. Sorry for your trouble.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem has been found by the OP to be caused by the package `beamerswitch`, as noted in the comments.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has reported in the comments that a problem with the package `beamerswirch` was the cause.